# How to display woocommerce subtotal of items only, before shipping or tax, on order detail page

Tags: woocommerce

With all plugins off and checking every setting, I can't get a subtotal for just the items on the order details page. Mine shows as:

```
Line item 1 $50
Line item 2 $60
Priority Mail $10
---------------------
Discount $0
Shipping $10
Order Total $120
Refunded -$0
```

However what I need is the order item subtotal:

```
Line item 1 $50
Line item 2 $60
ORDER ITEM SUBTOTAL $110
Priority Mail $10
---------------------
Discount $0
Shipping $10
Order Total $120
Refunded -$0
```

To declare the order value when shipping, we have to take the order total, subtract the shipping, then enter that value on the shipping form. Shouldn't there be an order item subtotal? I've shut off all plugins and checked all settings, I don't have one. Anyone know?

Comment: It repeats shipping without adding it in twice. Repeating it is silly, but the sample is correct. 50+60+10=120
https://postimg.org/image/wslj37yqv/

Comment: i had a problem posting that comment did you get the screenshot ok?

Comment: I would love to but skype broke my computer I ended up uninstalling it. I did figure a very poor way to do it, I suppose if I understood filters better it'd be an answer. 

/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-items.php

Line 17 add $order_subtotal =0;

Line 91 (Your mileage will vary on line numbers as I am commenting this as well)
echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>SUBTOTAL:</td><td>" . wc_price( wc_format_decimal( $order_subtotal, '' ), array( 'currency' => $order->get_order_currency() ) )."</td></tr>";

Comment: same directory: html-order-item.php
line 18 $order_subtotal += $item_subtotal;

Comment: It's embarrassing but I don't know how to add a filter to the admin includes code.

Comment: This is the admin order detail page. The particulars come from woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes